# how to remove all junk characters from a string in java

Tags: java

I have a string like below

```
String s="[01;31m[KINACTIVE[m[K=-1";
```

i need to remove all those junk characters [01;31m[ .

my actual output is INACTIVE=-1 but with this some junks are added.how to remove using java.

Comment: First question, how and from where did you got those junk characters if your actual output is `INACTIVE=-1`?

Comment: What do you call junk character?

Comment: I think he means the output he needs is INACTIVE=-1

Comment: your problem is not to remove junk characters..its why you add junk characters

Comment: I smell [XyProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). what actually you want to achieve? you want to _remove_ or you want to _avoid_ ?

Comment: i am getting this output from jsch shell i think its color of the string

Comment: @Ramakrishna If you redirect the jsch shell output to a *non-terminal*, it really should not include these extra escape sequences .. alternatively, maybe there is an option to "disable ANSI escapes/controls"?

Comment: how to disable ANSI escapes/controls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing there appear to be [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) and they're used to format console output, or at least that's the general idea.

I've used the top regular expression [here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3584/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed) before to remove the ANSI codes from Travis CI logs.

Comment: +1 For describing what the "junk" is. However, I would recommend simply getting the output *without* the junk/control sequences as a better approach, if it is at all possible.

Comment: @user2864740 In the real world, you might not be able to get some data without junk. It's good to know how to clean up messy data :)

Comment: thanks for the answer but the regular exp is not working in java

Comment: @Ramakrishna It needs to be converted per Java nuances, of course. Also make sure that your strings *really* contain the ESC character and that it wasn't lost during copy/paste or however the strings are loaded.

Comment: @Ramakrishna Try this `\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]`, and you might need to do a replace all (or similar).

Comment: this expression also not working still i am getting same Str.replaceAll("\\x1B\\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]", "");

Comment: @Ramakrishna Play around with it (I haven't done regex in Java), otherwise just hardcode the chars you need to remove.